# How to dynamically change FXG file?

Tags: apache-flex, runtime, fxg

I load my fxg and it's fine. But I want to change my fxg file in runtime, then i want to refresh my browser page and see my changes. Is it possible to do in flex?

Answer (score 1):

An FXG is compiled; so you can't change it at runtime.

Since you mention refreshing your browser page; there may be a way.  You may be able to modify the FXG in some manner; call a service that will use command line tools to recompile the project; and then when the browser is refreshed your updates should be shown.

You may be able to make this transparent to the user, without a formal page refresh, by using a "wrapper" application that just loads other SWFs via [SWFLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html).

Comment: Please can you explain about "wrapper" application. How I can load other SWF ? How I can get swf from fxg?

Comment: You can load a SWF using SWFLoader.  I edited the question to add a link to the class.  The "Wrapper" application would be an app that does nothing but load other SWFs.  You can get get a SWF from an FXG using the Flex compiler.  I assumed, based on your original question, that this is what you were already doing.

Comment: +1 ... since FXG's are compiled, you can't change their properties dynamically at runtime. If you want this functionality, you can use Spark graphics primitives like `Rect` (`<s:Rect />`). These allow you to change their properties, and have a very similar syntax to FXG. The tradeoff is they are a little heavier than their FXG counterparts. But you could get the dynamic behavior w/out having to refresh the page.